# How to sort (and give weight) by Availability dates in SolR

Tags: sorting, datetime, solr, availability

i'm facing a big problem in my SolR DB.
My objects have a datetime field "Available_From" and a datetime field "Available_To".
We also have a "Ranking" field for the sorting.
I can search correctly with direct queries (eg. give me all the items that are available at the moment) but when i do a regular search i cannot find a way to show the items that result "available NOW" in the first places in the results, usually sorted by "Ranking" field.
How can i do this? Am I forced to write some java classes (the nearest thing i've found is there https://medium.com/@devchaitu18/sorting-based-on-a-custom-function-in-solr-c94ddae99a12) or is there a way to do with standard SolR queries?
Thanks in advance to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you actually don't want sorting, since that indicates that you want one field to determine the returned sequence of documents.

Instead, use boosting - apply a very large boost to those that are available now, either through `bq` or `boost`, then apply a boost based on ranking. You'll have to tweak the weights given to each part based on how you want the search results to be presented.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering. i tried to add this bq, bq=(Avail_From: [* TO NOW] AND Avail_To: [NOW TO *])^10. but it did not work, what's wrong? and for the ranking, how can i add it to the bq, in the way that after the eventual results with the availability i have the results with the ranking sorted from bigger to lower ranking? thanks!!!

Comment: Append `debug=all` to see how the score is affected by your boosts. You can add another `bq` if you want, or use `boost` with the value (or `bf`).

Comment: thanks, i added "defType=edismax" before all and now the "available now" results come first, but how can i add the ranking part in the bq? i have to sort by "ranking" desc, but i cannot write &sort=Ranking+desc because it would overwhelm the bq... then it would be nice that also the "available now" resuls were ordered by rank! thanks!

Comment: That's where you introduce the `boost` with your ranking. You're not going to be able to absolutely order by rank, but since your "available now" is a boolean result - you could use that as the score through the magic [`_val_` field](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#TheExtendedDisMaxQueryParser-Usingthe_magicfields__val_and_query_), then order by score and then by rank.

Comment: Fantastic, sorting like this "score desc, Ranking desc" worked perfectly, thank you very much!!!